# Java nullpointerexception with bufferedimage.getrgb

Tags: java, arrays, image, nullpointerexception

Currently I want to get an array with the pixels of an image. I'm using this code now:

```
int[] pixels;
int width = firstfloorimg.getWidth();
int height = firstfloorimg.getHeight();

firstfloorimg.getRGB(0, 0, width, height, pixels, 0, width);
```

But than when i want to use the pixels array it gives a NullpointerException. I have used this code before with no errors.
Why does it occure and how do can I make this work?

Comment: `pixels` isn't initialized, you have just declared it.

Answer (score 0):

The Class `BufferedImage` offers two variants of `getRGB()` method:

1. **First one**, `int getRGB(int x, int y)` which will return a single pixel as the return type says.
2. **Second one**:

   ```
   int[] getRGB(int startX, int startY, int w, int h, 
                 int[] rgbArray, int offset, int scansize)
   ```

Which  Returns an array of integer pixels in the default RGB color model. However if your passed `rgbArray` is `null` this function will create a new `rgbArray` inside of it and return it:

```
public int[] getRGB(int startX, int startY, int w, int h,
                        int[] rgbArray, int offset, int scansize) {

    // other code      
    if (rgbArray == null) {
       rgbArray = new int[offset+h*scansize];
    }
   // other code
      return rgbArray;
    }
```

But again, you will have to assign the returned array to `pixels` before using it. The array that was created inside the `getRGB` function can't change the reference of `pixels` array which was `null` before passing to this function.

Consider using `getPixel(x, y)` function over the second one, because, unlike the second one,  `getPixel(x, y)` does  not throw away the  optimizations  made by Java2D. Discussing about it is out of the scope of this question.

**Reference:**

1. [BufferedImage.getRGB](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#getRGB%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%29)

Comment: Thank you this is exactly what I wanted to know